# SQL - ORDER BY running first

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please have a look at this database schema:

```
create table Person (id int not null identity,
                     [index] varchar(30),
                     datecreated datetime, 
                     groupid int)

create table [Group] (id int identity not null, description varchar(30))
```

Sample data:

```
insert into Person ([index],datecreated,groupid) values ('4,5,6','2011-01-01',1)
insert into Person ([index],datecreated,groupid) values ('1,2,3','2011-02-02',1)
insert into Person ([index],datecreated,groupid) values ('7,8','2012-02-02',2) 

insert into [Group] (description) values ('TestGroup')
insert into [Group] (description) values ('TestGroup2')
```

Please have a look at the SQL statement below:

```
select  *    
from Person 
inner join [Group] on Person.groupid = [group].id 
where [group].description = 'TestGroup' 
order by 
   left(substring([index], charindex(',', [index]) + 1, 200),  
        charindex(',', substring([index], charindex(',', [index]) + 1, 200)) - 1)
```

This SQL statement fails with the following error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

It is the `order by` clause that is causing this error i.e. it is trying to find the third element of the index column but the third element does not exist on row 3 (there are only two elements).

However, I would expect the `[group].description = 'TestGroup'` to filter out record three. This does not appear to be the case. It is as if the `order by` clause is being run before the `where` clause. If you exclude the `order by` clause from the query, then the query runs.

Why is this?

Comment: For testing: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29802/1

Comment: Why do you store comma separated values in that column? That is usually a sign of a very questionable DB design (and the problem you have is a result of that).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it is a system that I have inherited.  It needs redesigning.

Comment: Do you know what causes the GROUP BY clause to be considered first?

Comment: @marc_s, yes it does.  Have a look here and see for yourself: sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29802/1

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation order in SQL has very weak guaranteed. Probably the sort is performed first, then a stream aggregate. Nothing wrong with that by it self.

You cannot rely on execution order in general. Except in a case-expression which you can use to create a dummy value like `NULL` in your order by if the input for `SUBSTRING` would be invalid. **Case is the only way to enforce evaluation order.**

Comment: Execution plan in SQL is heavily dependent on the data and table statistics. It can change without warning or apparent provocation.

Comment: @JNK, interesting - case seems to be quite buggy. This fact changes my answer: Try it with CASE (because the docs say so!) and test it. Then hope it will start to crash later. Case is the last hope anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This ORDER BY is pretty brutal. I would suggest breaking this into a couple of queries, using a temp-table or table sub-expression, so you can do your filtering first, and/or create a column containing the data to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural language.  That is, you describe the result sets that you want.  You depend on the SQL compiler/optimizer to set up the execution plan.

Very typically, a SQL engine will have a component that reads the data from the table and does all the calculations that are needed for that data.  Of course, this includes calculations in the SELECT clause, but also calculations in "ON" clauses, "WHERE" clauses, and "ORDER BY" clauses.

The engine can then do the filtering *after* reading the data.  This enables the engine to readily use computed values for the filtering.

I am not saying that all databases work this way.  What I am saying is that there is no guarantee of the order of operations in a SQL statement.  This situation is one of the cases where doing things in the wrong order results in an error, which prevents the SQL from completing.  Do you want help rewriting the query so it doesn't get the error?